# Slack bot can share file but not post message while not in channel

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api

I am especially new to slack web api and bots. My question is what is the reason stands behind the inability of bot users to post messages into a channel, until they are implicitly invited, despite the fact that on behalf of a bot we can upload a file to it. Below are couple of code snippets

i've requested the following scopes `chat:write:user`  `bot` `files:write:user`

when I upload a file with a bot token obtained via OAuth2 the file is present in a channel with a bot icon and name

```
.token(BOT_TOKEN)
            .title("title")
            .content("content")
            .channels(Collections.singletonList("#channel"))
            .build();
```

but when I using the same approach trying to post a message to the same channel I get an error not_in_channel

```
.token(BOT_TOKEN)
            .channel("#channel")
            .text("text")
            .asUser(true)
```

i know it is working without passing as user true however it sets the default application icon and name not the bots one.

Is there a way to publish messages/upload files to a channel without users interaction after the authentication with a bot.

Comment: So, while not in that channel you can upload files and you can send messages as bot (with as_user = false) to that channel. Can you please specify in more what is not working and what you want to achieve?

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Thanks for the response, when I'm trying to post messages with a bot token and pass as_user = false that is a default value the message is published on behalf of my APP not the bot user, my app has different ICON and name and afterwards when I'm uploading a file that actually comes on behalf of my BOT user with its ICON and name it looks weird. 2 messages sent from different icons and names.  However when I change the as_user flag to true I'm getting an error that the bot is not inside the channel though I'm able to upload files to it. If its still unclear I can post the screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here seams to be that the icon and username are different when first posting a message to a channel as bot and later uploading a file as bot. This seams to be a known issue for Slack. This is what is said in the documentation for [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#authorship) for `as_user` is `false`:

> Note: In the Slack App cases above, it would certainly make more sense
>   for your application's name to be the default username associated with
>   your app. This inconsistent behavior will be corrected. Of course, you
>   can still name your bot "bot," if that is your bot's name.

But there is a workaround to get the same username and icon. Just set them manually when sending the message, e.g.:

```
curl -F token=BOT_TOKEN -F channel=CHANNEL -F text=Hello -F username=NAME_OF_BOT -F icon_url=ICON_URL https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage
```

Comment: it wasn't very obvious anyway. it would make much more sense to let the bot posting a message in case of setting as user flag to true if you have  certain permissions granted. thanks for you help @ErikKalkoken very much appreciated